# Connect existing nodejs express API with react-admin

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-admin

I have an existing nodejs and express API for shopping cart. I want to integrate this API with react-admin.
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin.
I have added the following code to app.js file to load the categories from database.

```
// in src/App.js
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import restProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';

import { CategoriesList } from './categories';

const App = () => (
  <Admin dataProvider={restProvider('http://localhost:5000/api')}>
    <Resource name="categories" list={CategoriesList} />
  </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

But it keeps throwing the following errors:

The Content-Range header is missing in the HTTP Response. The simple REST data provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare Content-Range in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?

Also, modified the code on server side to include these headers as below:

```
/**
 * GET request to retrieve all categories
 */
router.get('/api/categories', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const categories = await Category.find({});
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Range');
        res.setHeader('Content-Range', 5);
        res.send({ data: categories, total: 5 });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`error in getting categories ${error}`);
    }
})
```

Has anyone worked before with react-admin. What am I missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: hi how could you solve your problem? I am getting the same error, can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your `Content-Range` header is wrong. It must have the following format:

```
Content-Range: categories 0-5/5
```

See https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-simple-rest

Comment: I modified the following code:
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Range');
        res.setHeader('Content-Range', 'categories 0 - 5 / 5');
        res.send({ data: categories, total: 5 });
But still it did not work.

Comment: The following code on the server side works:
        const categories = await Category.find({});
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Range');
        res.setHeader('Content-Range', `categories 0 - 2 / ${categories.length}`);
        res.send(categories);
But while rendering on the client side, it gives the following error:
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
and does not render more than one category.

Comment: That's probably because your resources don't have an `id` prop. If you have an identifier field not named `id` then you must translate it in your `dataProvider`. See https://marmelab.com/react-admin/FAQ.html#can-i-have-custom-identifiersprimary-keys-for-my-resources

Comment: yeah these changes work. But the following line of code:
res.setHeader('Content-Range', `categories 0 - 5 / ${categories.length}`);
does not affect the pagination in any way. So how does pagination work in react-admin?